# not able to do max width

Tags: css

I have a page which has a content like this...

```
<div id="content">
testingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtesting
testingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtesting
testingtestingtestingtestingtesting
</div>
```

How do i apply a max-width on it . I m using this code in the css

```
#content {
    max-width:50px; /* for standards-compliant browsers */
   /*width:expression(document.body.clientwidth > 650? "650px": "auto" );*/ 
   /* max-width expression for IE only */
}
```

but i m not getting the results in firefox...
http://pradyut.dyndns.org/WebApplicationSecurity/width.jsp

Are there any JavaScript solutions? 
Any help 
thanks 
Pradyut

Comment: If you go to http://www.css3.com/, in the middle column, you should see a list of the current set of CSS tags up to CSS Level 3.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, in your CSS, you can set the [`word-wrap` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-wrap) to `break-word` so that your string of text (w/ no whitespace) will be made to fit into the max-width:

E.g.

```
<style type="text/css">

#content {
    max-width: 50px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

</style>
```

Comment: FYI, word-wrap is a CSS3 style tag, so it may not validate w/ current validators; but, I believe most browsers support the tag.

Comment: thanks for the help...really appreciate if you can share a link to the latest in css..

Comment: With a `<span>` it will also need `display:block` or `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 26):

Well the reason why you not getting the expected result on the page you provided by the link is that you are using a `span` instead of a `div`.

Add

```
display: block;
```

to you style.

Answer (score 15):

```
#content {
    max-width: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

You may like to remove `display: inline-block;` depending on the context of your element.

Comment: What is the use of ellipsis?

Comment: It truncates the text, and replaces the last 3 characters with periods, like: This is some truncated t...

Comment: @ekerner it replaces the text with the single character '…' & should only replace as many characters as necessary (… need only replace ww in 'awww')

Comment: Thanks, the inline-block is very importang.

Answer (score 6):

If you used your own example you would find that [it works just fine](http://jsbin.com/itiba).  The page you linked to uses a `span` element, which is an inline element by default.  Inline elements cannot have width or height.  If you want to set max width on a span element, set it's display to block or inline-block:

```
<span id="content" style="max-width:50px; display:block;" >  
testingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtesting  
testingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtesting  
testingtestingtestingtestingtesting  
</span>
```

Comment: well changed the page... still the same... please help

Comment: well there are no line breaks in the whole line "testing...testing"
your page contains line breaks...
please help...

Answer (score -2):

Add spaces in between. I believe this occurs because css/html reads it as one word. eg..

```
<span id="content" style="max-width:50px; display:block;" >  
testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing  
testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing  
testing testing testing testing testing  
</span>
```